# Creating Fama French 3- factors regression loops in R

Tags: r, loops

I am working on the estimation of ***3-Fama-French Factors*** and 4-Fama-French Factor models for each stock from a large dataset ***crsp***.
I am wondering what syntax I should run in R to create a loop for each company to generate its respective Fama-french regression. I've tried a few loops code suggested in here, but they didn't work. my data table ***crsp*** looks like this:
[screenshot of crsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YIdf.png)

in console, it looks like

```
Browse[1]> head(crsp)
         date                       COMNAM PERMNO SICCD    PRC    VOL       RET SHROUT
1: 1995-01-31                       AMERCO  81073  6710 19.750   3367  0.136691  32857
2: 1995-01-31            AMERICAN ECO CORP  76481  3089  2.125    295 -0.170732   6822
3: 1995-01-31         AMERICAN STUDIOS INC  77901  7220  2.750   3075  0.000000  21426
4: 1995-01-31                ANGELICA CORP  45583  2337 26.375   3374 -0.045249   9458
5: 1995-01-31 ASSISTED LIVING CONCEPTS INC  81051  8059  7.750   1348 -0.088235   3000
6: 1995-01-31              BLOCK H & R INC  49373  7299 35.750 108603 -0.037037 105596
   capitalization   dateff mktrf     smb    hml     rf     umd year
1:      648925.75 19950131 0.018 -0.0353 0.0254 0.0042 -0.0182 1995
2:       14496.75 19950131 0.018 -0.0353 0.0254 0.0042 -0.0182 1995
3:       58921.50 19950131 0.018 -0.0353 0.0254 0.0042 -0.0182 1995
4:      249454.75 19950131 0.018 -0.0353 0.0254 0.0042 -0.0182 1995
5:       23250.00 19950131 0.018 -0.0353 0.0254 0.0042 -0.0182 1995
6:     3775057.00 19950131 0.018 -0.0353 0.0254 0.0042 -0.0182 1995
```

I need to estimate 95 companies, and the numbers of monthly data of each company are not identical, in total there are 6000+ observations.

So far, I regressed on one company called AMERCO using 300+ observations exclusive to AMERCO, and I coded as followed:

```
### calculate excess return for AMERCO
crsp[, retrf := RET - rf]
AMERCO_PERMNO<- 81073
crsp.AMERCO <- crsp[PERMNO == AMERCO_PERMNO]
View(crsp.AMERCO)

# run 3 FFF for AMERCO
fit2 <- feols(retrf ~ mktrf + smb + hml, data = crsp.AMERCO)
summary(fit2)
```

This returns well on the regression for AMERCO, but now I don't know where to move next to regress all the rest 94 companies' data in one loop.

I am a new user of R-studio, will be grateful for your help!
Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `split` + `lapply` approach :

```
lapply(split(crsp, crsp$PERMNO), function(x) {
  fit2 <- feols(retrf ~ mktrf + smb + hml, data = x)
  summary(fit2)
}) -> result
```

And the same with `by` :

```
by(crsp, crsp$PERMNO, function(x) {
  fit2 <- feols(retrf ~ mktrf + smb + hml, data = x)
  summary(fit2)
}) -> result
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks for your answer, I tried your code, they did return all results for each company, however, the results are identical from a general Fama french model based on all 6000+ observations, is there a way to improve this code by each company runs their exclusive regression only based on their own corresponding data ? Many thanks!

Comment: This code runs regression for each `PERMNO` separately on their own data.

Comment: I ran the code, but the contents of 95 output are all the same, it did not use the company's exclusive data, just a whole picture of all data.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're using for the regression, `feols`, is designed for more complex problems.  Simple regression using the function `lm` should work fine for Fama-French.  A straightforward way to do this is:

```
fit2 <- sapply(unique(crsp$COMNAM),
               FUN = function(x) { fit = lm(RET ~ mktrf + smb + hml,
                                            data = crsp,
                                            subset = (COMNAM == x) ); 
                                   coef(fit) }) 
fit2 <- t(fit2)
```

Alternatively, using the `split` function as Ronak Shah did,

```
fit3 <-  sapply(split(crsp, crsp$COMNAM),
             FUN = function(x) { fit = lm(RET ~ mktrf + smb + hml,
                                          data = x ); 
             coef(fit) })
fit3 <- t(fit3)
```